# How do I make the international part in phone optional

Tags: php, preg-match

I want to make the International code optional in regex.

```
<?php
$phone = 'abcd +89-800-123-4567 efgh';
$string = preg_replace("/([\+][0-9]{1,6}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})/", '<a href="tel:$1" id="phone">$1</a>', $phone);
echo $string;
?>
```

If I try 800-123-4567 only it should also work. I tried the optional group using ?: but for some reason it is not working. Here is my sample code

```
(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})
```

Comment: `?:` is not an "optional grouping" it makes the group "non-capturing". A `?` after a grouping makes in optional. Maybe https://regex101.com/r/NFMAbk/1/ is what you intend?

Comment: It works good but it matches abcd +89800-123-4567 efgh with the last ten digits also it should fail in this case.

Comment: Maybe https://regex101.com/r/NFMAbk/2/ is better? Providing multiple sample strings will improve the question, and accuracy of answers.

Comment: You could use a word boundary `\b` before the first 3 digits. See https://regex101.com/r/8cTyNS/1 If you don't need the capturing groups you could omit them.

Answer (score 0):

You missed an hyphen between optional part and rest of the phone number:

```
(?:\+?\d{1,3}-)?[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}
//    here __^
```